# integrate carbon/ react datepicker in ag- grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Hi I am trying to implement carbon/react datepicker component in ag-grid. here I done some code can anyone help me here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-date-picker-tvcawe?file=package.json,customDateComponent.js

```
   import React, {
  Component,
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
} from 'react';

// import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import { DatePicker, DatePickerInput } from '@carbon/react';

// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

const CustomDateComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const [picker, setPicker] = useState(null);
  const refDatePicker = useRef();
  const refInput = useRef();

  const onDateChanged = (selectedDate) => {
    setDate(selectedDate);
    props.onDateChanged();
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getDate() {
      return date;
    },

    setDate(date) {
      setDate(date);
    },
  }));

  return (
    <DatePicker
      ref={refDatePicker}
      // id="root"
      datePickerType="single"
      className="ag-custom-component-popup"
      onChange={onDateChanged}
    >
      <DatePickerInput />
    </DatePicker>
  );
});

export default CustomDateComponent;
```

Comment: Here is the carbon/react url  [link](https://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/components-datepicker--single-with-calendar)